What do these bntx console errors mean?
I have a server spilling out the following errors to the console
bnxt_en 0000:c8:00.1 bnxt_rel: Failed to add GID: Oxfffffff2  
infiniband bnxt_rel: add roce_gid GID add failed port=1 index=2  
bnxt_en 0000:c8:00.1: QPLIB: cndg[0x7b]=0x11 status 0x1  

screenshot
I can not figure out what it is trying to say or how to even diagnose the issue further.
This machine is running a Proxmox linux kernel 6.5.
Supermicro H12SSW-NT motherboard.
Upgrading to kernel 6.8 makes the machine freeze even. With 6.5 at least it runs (besides spamming the screen).

Looks like you hit this problem. Pin the old kernel (6.5) for now. Broadcom driver messages are probably not related, so this comment doesn't address the main question (in the title) anyway.
